# rails 3 - namespace - viewer helper generate wrong route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, namespaces, routes

I have this namespace:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :users
end
```

When I try use `admin_users_url(User.last)` the url generated is: http://test.host/admin/users.1
it should be: http://test.host/admin/users/1

Someone can help me?

Comment: Other than the noticeable spelling error in `namespace :adim` ? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

Comment: No... I wrote this as a simple example. My real code is different.

Comment: Ops.. sorry, I mean that the code above it's equal my real code but I just change the names...

Answer (score 1):

What you want to call is:

```
admin_user_url(User.last)
```

You're accessing a specific resource, so the route name is singular, not plural.

Also, use **rake routes** to check your route names and paths.